# Unable to enable Bluetooth 14.04

Tags: bluetooth

I'm unable to enable bluetooth. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and when I go to *Settings → Bluetooth*, this shows up:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/isdvi.png]

I can't click the switch to turn Bluetooth on and off.

Output of `dmesg | grep Bluetooth`:

```
[   29.412813] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   29.412828] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   29.412836] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   29.412838] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   29.412842] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   29.415260] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   29.415263] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   29.415272] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   29.415974] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   29.415984] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   29.415985] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ffhnHpGw

Comment: Same result, I still can't enable bluetooth

Comment: I put it in my question. Also the answer you gave to me still didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the output of `rfkill list`?

Comment: 0: phy0: Wireless LAN                                               Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

Comment: Is there no bluetooth option?

Comment: No there isn't. Is that bad?

Comment: Does bluetooth show up when you run `lsusb`?

Comment: No, bluetooth doesn't show anywhere in that command.

Comment: You may not have a bluetooth adapter in your system, which is why you are not able to turn on bluetooth...

Comment: Huh. What's a bluetooth adapter...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Computer_requirements

Answer (score 0):

Install the Bluetooth drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco \
bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump \
bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez \
bluewhoindicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev  libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3
```

Edit the `rc.local` file -

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

Add the following line -

`rfkill unblock bluetooth`

Reboot the system and check again.